# Configuring Ubuntu as a webserver for tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, tomcat, tomcat6, confluence

Our SysAdmin has been in an accident and is out of action (Coma) for a while and we're in desperate need of setting up Confluence on our clients domain, as the resident "java drinker" at work I've been tasked with setting up Tomcat+Confluence on an Ubuntu LTS server.

Honestly I don't know much about the sysadmin stuff and need some guidance. I have a Ubuntu server, we have a domain and we need to ensure that wiki.ourclientsdomain.com points to our tomcat instance.

Do I need to update my /etc/hosts entry so that it will accept the subdomain and tell it to point directly to my tomcat? Do I need to setup an Apache proxy or are there any guides out there for these basic things?

We're unable to recruit or hire a sysadmin at short notice, so any help would be greatly appreciated. We were using a control panel before on our windows machines (Plesk?) but we have none in this new "self hosted" solution our admin got us.

The main [client].com is running on IIS6 hosted in our office, I'm not allowed to touch that, we use Plesk to configure that and add A records etc for the domain as well as manage IIS duties if required.

Essentially, I'd like to do this on our Ubuntu LTS.

- Setup Tomcat with just Confluence (this I can do fine)
- Have wiki.[client].com point to /confluence on the tomcat box (need help here)
- host a lighttpd instance to serve our files when they goto downloads.[client].com (the above will help me with the DNS bits, I can setup the server and probably setup some vhosts?)

Do I need to install bind9 to manage the DNS's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to hear about your sysadmin, and wish them the best for their recovery.

Tomcat on Ubuntu is about as hard as `apt-get install tomcat6`.  To get your clients resolving  wiki.client.com you need to make that change on whatever their DNS server is.  It sounds like you can ask someone to add this record in Plesk.

As for Apache, [there are already very suitable guides to doing this](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy).

Good luck!

Comment: cool! I realise that its not as hard as it looks now :) thanks!